# Difference between 'merging' and 'matching' procedure

Tags: particle-physics, scattering, beyond-the-standard-model

For combining scattering processes with different jet-multiplicities 
in the final state, higher order corrections and parton shower, merging/matching procedures need to be applied to avoid double-counting.

In e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.5467 they are defined the following way:

> - *merging* multileg matrix elements at tree level
> - *matching* parton shower simulations and perturbative calculations
>     at next-to-leading order (NLO)

At another place, they are defined as:

> - *Matching*: Combine a higher-order calculation (NLO, NNLO, ...)  for
>     one jet multiplicity with showers such as to preserve the respective  order order expansion.
> - *Merging*: Combine calculations (LO, NLO, ...)  for
>     several jet multiplicities with showers such as to 
>     reproduce the respective order expansion (and Sudakov suppression) in each jet bin.

However, I found that **LO matching** is also used in the literature.
(e.g. http://home.fnal.gov/~skands/slides/dis_050427.pdf ) which would not be possible due to the definitions above.

Is there a clear distinction between both?